# Are there any usability studies around facebook like social user interfaces?

Tags: social-media

Are there any usability studies around facebook like social user interfaces? Please share.

Comment: Do you mean facebook-like or the "Like" feature on facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a great article on usability principles for social media. It includes a number of examples from web 2.0 driven sites, and discusses their strengths and weaknesses.

http://creativebriefing.com/applications-of-usability-principles-on-a-social-network/

Sorry if that is not exactly what you are looking for; the question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps: [Designing Social Interfaces](http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns/Main_Page) by Christian Crumlish and Erin Malone. I haven't read it, though. Looks like there are lot's of social media patterns published on the website and some discussions around it. But maybe you are interested in Facebook-only stuff.